# Angular - Access config injected dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

When I try to access the $location variable injected into the config from my resolve route, I get a "Unknown Provider" error in the console.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $location) {

$location.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider.when('/', {

        templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
        controller:'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: "vm",
        resolve:{
                getData: function(){

                  var param = $location.search().options


                }

       }
    })
```

Shouldn't the $location parameter be accessible like a closure? I'm fairly new to JS and Angular, so I need clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the array notation, then the strings must match what you're injecting. in this case, if you want to use `$location`, you should inject `$location`, not `$locationProvider`

Comment: It works fine without having the same variable name as the array item.

The $location.html5Mode(true); works as intended.